# make: *** No rule to make target s1_c1.o, needed by s1_c1

Tags: c, makefile

I'm new to make and I'm trying to build multiple binaries at once that all depend on the same objects. My makefile looks like this :

```makefile
BINARY=s1_c1 s1_c2 s1_c3

CODEDIRS=./challenges ./src 

INCDIRS=. ./include/

COMPILER=gcc
OPT=-O2 
DEBUG=-Og 

DEPFLAGS=-MP -MD

CFLAGS1=-Wall -g $(foreach D, $(INCDIRS), -I$(D)) $(DEBUG) $(DEPFLAGS)
CFLAGS2=-Wall $(foreach D, $(INCDIRS), -I$(D)) $(DEPFLAGS)

CFILES=$(foreach D, $(CODEDIRS), $(wildcard $(D)/*.c))
MAINCFILES = $(foreach V, $(CFILES), $(if $(filter ./challenges/% , $V),$V))

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(CFILES))

MAINOBJECTS = $(foreach V, $(OBJECTS), $(if $(filter ./challenges/% , $V),$V))
LIBOBJECTS = $(foreach V, $(OBJECTS), $(if $(filter ./src/% , $V),$V))

DEPFILES = $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(CFILES))

all : $(BINARY)

.PHONY: all


s1_c1 : $(LIBOBJECTS) s1_c1.o
    $(COMPILER) (-o) $@ $^

s1_c2 : $(LIBOBJECTS) s1_c2.o
    $(COMPILER) (-o) $@ $^

s1_c3 : $(LIBOBJECTS) s1_c3.o
    $(COMPILER) (-o) $@ $^

%.o : %.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS1) -c -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -rf $(BINARY) $(LIBOBJECTS) $(DEPFILES)
```

The source files for the s1_c* that contain main functions are in a directory called ./challenges, the others are in the ./src directory. The ./include contains the .h of the ./src. And the binaries should be built in another directory called bin. And every directory is in a main directory containing the makefile. When I run make I get the error in the title. I'm guessing the problem comes from my misunderstanding of automatic variables and pattern rules but I can't get it right with the gnu doc. Thank you in advance !

Comment: The rule `s1_c1 : $(LIBOBJECTS) s1_c1.o` says that `s1_c1` needs a file `s1_c1.o`.  But you haven't told make how to build a file like that, and one doesn't exist already, so make gives you that error.  You have a file `challenges/s1_c1.c` but make has no way to know that this file could be used to build a target `s1_c1.o`: the paths are different.  If you change your rule to depend on `challenges/s1_c1.o` instead then make should be able to build it.

Comment: Oh right ! thanks yeah that works, would it be possible to avoid building each binary separately, I mean writing a line for each of them ? I tried targetting BINARY directly and putting challenges/$@.o in the prerequisite but $@ is empty apparently if I put it in the prerequisite

Comment: This is where using a better `Makefile` template with more generic rules can help *considerably*.

Comment: Do you have any template or ressource I could use to do it better ?

Comment: That's what pattern rules are for; you already use a pattern rule for building object files.  There's no reason you can't also use one for building binaries.

Comment: (BTW I have no idea why you are putting parentheses around your option `(-o)` but that can't work can it?

Comment: that's a typo I had it removed. Ah right with something of the form %: %.o $(LIBOBJECTS) I guess ? I need to learn the reach of %, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments you need to add the directory name for challenges to tell make where to find those .o files.
That combined with pattern rules gives you a much shorter makefile.

```makefile
    BINARY=s1_c1 s1_c2 s1_c3 
    
    CODEDIRS=./challenges ./src 
    
    INCDIRS=. ./include/
    
    COMPILER=gcc
    OPT=-O2 
    DEBUG=-Og 
    
    DEPFLAGS=-MP -MD
    
    CFLAGS1=-Wall -g $(foreach D, $(INCDIRS), -I$(D)) $(DEBUG) $(DEPFLAGS)
    CFLAGS2=-Wall $(foreach D, $(INCDIRS), -I$(D)) $(DEPFLAGS)
    
    CFILES=$(foreach D, $(CODEDIRS), $(wildcard $(D)/*.c))
    
    OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(CFILES))
    
    LIBOBJECTS = $(foreach V, $(OBJECTS), $(if $(filter ./src/% , $V),$V))
    
    DEPFILES = $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(CFILES))
    
    all : $(BINARY)
    
    .PHONY: all
    
    $(BINARY): %: $(LIBOBJECTS) challenges/%.o 
        $(COMPILER)  -o $@ $^
    
    %.o : %.c
        $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS1) -c -o $@ $^
    
    clean:
        rm -rf $(BINARY) $(LIBOBJECTS) $(DEPFILES)
```

Comment: Would be great if you accept my answer if it works for you :)